# Electric field round a rectangular conductive plate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, harmonic-functions

Can the solution to the laplace equation with boundary conditions that $u=1$ on a rectangular plate (ie $|x|<a, |y|<b, z=0$) and $\lim_{r\to\infty} u=0$ be expressed in closed form?

Comment: I would try posting this question on the Physics SE, it seems more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my first guess would be no, since I only know of explicit Poisson kernels for the disk/ball and upper half-space.

Comment: @Victor I disagree, I think that the question wether a differential equation has a closed form solution is more math than it's physics.